# Multiple URLs for the same WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, url, seo, canonicalization

I'm developing a site that offers services to different locations. However, the services and the landing page for all visitors will be the same.

I would like to have multiple "paths" from the same domain that all lead to the same landing page. So for example

```
http://example.com/London
http://example.com/Manchester
http://example.com/Sheffield
```

all leading to the same page. This seems to be a popular concept with some sites that I've noticed. For example, if I Google search for "House Removals Doncaster", the site http://www.anyvan.com/Doncaster will show up, but if you click it it takes you to the same landing page for the main site. Same goes for if you search "House Removals London", http://www.anyvan.com/London shows up but still directs you to the same page.

I'm not an expert at SEO but I'm sure there must be the correct terminology to describe this method. Is it canonicalization? I read up on that a bit but it wasn't quite what I was looking for.

Also, are there any SEO benefits to be gained from doing this? Surely there must be if the bigger companies are employing this method?

I'm developing the site in WordPress. Any help in understanding how this is achieved or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The two examples from anyvan.com redirect to the lowercased variant and give me 404.

Answer (score -3):

You can create multiple pages through the wp-admin feature, and then simply redirect your visitors to your main webpage using the following code on your extra pages:

```
<?php header("Location: http://example.com/mainpage"); ?>
```

Make sure you have a plugin that activates php code so this can work. Post Snippets (https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-snippets/) would function, or just choose another of your choice.

Comment: He doesn't want to redirect but show the same page on different URLs.